# Why are so many strange certificate filenames ending with 0 in /etc/ssl/certs?

Tags: ssl, certificates

As we know that CA certificates locate in `/etc/ssl/certs` in debian.

```
cd  /etc/ssl/certs
ls | grep  0$ |wc -l
126
```

I paset part of them here:

```
f081611a.0
f0c70a8d.0
f249de83.0
f30dd6ad.0
f3377b1b.0
f387163d.0
f39fc864.0
f51bb24c.0
fc5a8f99.0
fe8a2cd8.0
```

Why are so many strange certificate filenames ending with 0 in /etc/ssl/certs ?

Comment: If you check you'll find these are all symlinks to files with more descriptive names. My guess would be that those numbers are some kind of id/checksum (and ".0" simply a convention) making it easier to find/reference the correct certificate in certain cases.

Comment: ls -al   93bc0acc.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Aug 18  2021 93bc0acc.0 -> AffirmTrust_Networking.pem
,it is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These values are hashed results of certificates (to be precise: today the hash is based on the [SHA1 hash of the subject (DN)](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/openssl/openssl-x509.1ssl#HISTORY) in canonical form) to speed up their lookup.
The last digit is an index in the linked list of elements hashing to the same value in case a [hash collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) happens.

This is documented in [`openssl rehash`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssl/openssl-rehash.1ssl):

> **rehash** scans directories and calculates a hash value of each
> ".pem",    ".crt", ".cer", or ".crl" file in the specified directory
> list and    creates **symbolic links** for each file, where **the name of
> the link is the    hash value**.  (If the platform does not support
> symbolic links, a copy    is made.)  **This utility is useful as many
> programs that use OpenSSL    require directories to be set up like
> this in order to find    certificates**.

As for the last digit (which will be 0 until a hash collision happens):

> The links created are of the form "HHHHHHHH.D", where each H is a
> hexadecimal character and D is a single decimal digit.  When
> processing    a directory, rehash will first remove all links that
> have a name in    that syntax, even if they are being used for some
> other purpose.  To    skip the removal step, use the -n flag.  Hashes
> for CRL's look similar    except the letter r appears after the
> period, like this: "HHHHHHHH.rD".
>
> **Multiple objects may have the same hash; they will be indicated by
> incrementing the D value**. Duplicates are found by comparing the full SHA-1 fingerprint. A warning will be displayed if a duplicate is
> found.

Comment: Nit: a cert's _fingerprint_ is a hash of the whole cert, but the hash used here is of the subject name for cert, or the issuer name for CRL; see `-hash/-subject_hash` and `-subject_hash_old` options on `x509` man page and `-hash` and `-hash_old` options on `crl` man page, also `-CApath` option on `verify` man page.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks. I wasn't thinking, the hash has to be there to speedup a search based on the subject when validating a cert so of course has to be based on useful input data that is available beforehand (unlike the fingerprint which is available only once found).